# Browser shows a blank page because of <?xml ... ?> in the beginning of the html-file

Tags: php, html, xml, apache

Firstly I want to tell you a bit about the background.

I've got a little problem here and it seems like it began after a server attack that we have had here last week. We were using an old webshop (ok, not really using, but it was there) and someone have found a hole in it, uploaded some exploits and got a root. One thing he used was a script called suhosin.sh, that installed some kind of fake plugin and edited the php.ini, so that this plugin was executed every time a page was loaded. So far I could delete everything that I could find and blocked many holes on our server, but it seems like something is still wrong with php or apache or both or something else.

Now the problem is, that I have noticed, that some of html pages on a website shows blank page with a lenght of 0 in the http-header. The pages were generated by an eLearning platform called Ilias, so that could be simply uploaded to a server as an eLearning module, so they are all static and were showing up normally in the past, before the mentioned above happened, as well as they work on another server and localhost.

I first thought it was a php problem and tried to do something in php.ini, but nothing worked out good so far. Than I noticed following:

Strange thing is that as far as I remove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

from the very beginning of the page, it works! So that would probably have something to do with apache, that I don't know why can't show that kind of page, that it seems like is being recognized as xml.

I already tried to compare php.ini with the one on another server, I don't really know where that kind of stuff can be configurated in apache or w/e, so I hope someone could help me to find the right direction, googling in all 3 languages that I "know" doesn't help much. :(

And well, I want to apologise for my english, that's the first time that I have to ask something like that, but am slowly getting a bit frustrated and getting out of time because of deadline...

Hope someone will help. If you want to know anything about the php or apache config or w/e, ask, I could provide almost everything.

Alex

---

**Problem solved!**

Could either be solved by:

1) "short_open_tag = Off" in php.ini

2) removing "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" from .htaccess as well as /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: The server was compromised and you've just been patching it? Stop! Pull the server off-line for analysis. Put a clean one in its place. Make sure the clean one has up to date software on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<?` is one of the delimiters for PHP code. If they are static HTML pages, they should not be parsed by the PHP interpreter in the first place! Unluckily, there are just too many ways to tell Apache that certain file is PHP code, but chances are that you have an `.htaccess` file somewhere with this code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

However, you should really wipe out everything in your server and restore from either your local development copy of the software or a clean backup. There are just too many places where malware can hide.

Comment: The global .htaccess under /var/lib/php5/ already had it, but it also have had a line that was prepending another malicious script, so thank you very much for your comment even if it was helpful in another way. :)

Comment: Stupid thing about the server is that I am just working at this company for a couple of months as a web developer and the guy who was there before me installed the server and everything, but it seems that there were no backups up and running, not even syslog was working properly, auth messages weren't logged at all, and stuff like that, so there are no backps... And that kinda sucks! Not to mention that it isn't even my job and installing servers isn't something that I am comfortable with =/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you the same as @Quentin did, take the server offline and investigate. Don't try to patch it while it's still online.

The issue with the `<?xml` might be related to `short_open_tag`, make sure this one is off in the `php.ini`.

Comment: That worked out fine, thank you! Howewer, it is set 'On' on another server (my own), as well as localhost. And yes, we already have ordered a new server so we could reup this one. Thanks!